# MySQL Update from PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

As a novice MySQL user I tried to insert, but I just read on the MySQL documentation that you can only insert on blank rows.  My UPDATE statement needs work though, and I'm not sure that I have the syntax correct.

```
$query3 = "UPDATE `offices` SET `scash`="$total" WHERE `officename`="$office"";
```

offices is the table name.  scash is the row to be updated.  $total is a variable pulled from a post. $office is a variable pulled from the same database.  I only want to set scash to total where the officename is $office.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE is the error I'm getting.

Comment: Please learn how to use [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) before you hurt yourself. This query is **extremely** dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query3 = "UPDATE `offices` SET `scash`='$total' WHERE `officename`='$office'";
```

Replace the double quotes with normal quotes in the string since double quotes are string delimiters and can't  be used in the string.

And as Marc B mentioned your code might be vurnerable for SQL injections. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) how you can avoid that.

Comment: and for the average php novice, better mention something about [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts.  I don't know what I'd do without you guys.

Comment: The best way to say thanks is to learn PDO or `mysqli` so you don't fall into this trap again in the future.

Comment: I'm on my way to learning mysqli, unfortunately, I'm under a time crunch right now, so this is the route I have to take.  I can update my code as of next week.

Answer (score 1):

You are going wrong at quotes

```
$query3 = "UPDATE `offices` SET `scash`="$total" WHERE `officename`='$office'";
```

Also always use **`LIMIT 1`** if you want to update just a single row...

And sanitize your inputs before updating your row, atleast use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Using `LIMIT 1` on an `UPDATE` is bad advice. Your `WHERE` clause should be more specific if you're having limit issues.

Comment: Yes, there is harm. It makes no sense, for one, and secondly leads to a false sense of security. Randomly updating one row is crazy.

Comment: The problem with `LIMIT 1` is you don't get to say *what* row. MySQL will just pick one randomly for you, which leads to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Additionally, if you're using `mysqli` and somehow involve `mysqli_real_escape_string` in your code you're doing it wrong. Please use placeholders for all data escaping.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause doesn't have a limit, the `UPDATE` does. It's generally wrong to do this. You really don't have a leg to stand on here.

Answer (score 1):

if you still want to use double quotes inside double quotes escape it..

your query can be modified as follows..

```
$query3 = "UPDATE `offices` SET `scash`=\"$total\" WHERE `officename`=\"$office\"";
```